# How to achieve constant width for barcodes; regardless of barcode-data

Tags: label, barcode, barcode-scanner, barcode-printing

Currently I'm programming a label-writer (Brother QL-570, if it matters, in Java) to print barcodes with different ID's. The length of the barcode data can vary from ~17 characters to ~3.

However, given that I've understood the barcode-concept correctly, the more data - the wider will the barcode become.

I'd prefer if all barcodes had the same, contstant size: no matter data-length. (It won't look good if the barcode doesn't fill up the label, nor will it (work) if it's too large)

**How can one handle this when the labels are at a fixed size (i.e 29mm x 90mm)?** How did you / your company solve this problem? 2D-barcodes aren't an option. Sadly.

[image]

Comment: I'm not a barcode expert, but could you pad it? is `123` different from `00000000000000123` ?

Comment: @durron597 I don't think so, the max-data-length depends on the number of items in the database, 17 didgits is an approximate with 10.000 items in the database; there's no guarantee that I will ever have so many items. Nor is there any guarantee that I won't have more..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's going to look kinda funny if you have to compare barcodes of different widths side-by-side, but my company solved it by defining each symbol in terms of a 1x?? bitmap and scaling it up to the size required for the application. For example, each code 128 symbol, except Stop, is eleven pixels wide. Our "font" then has 107 characters defined, each a 1x11 black and white bitmap (PNG).

It makes fitting the barcode into the space provided much simpler if you have that much control over vertical and horizontal dimensioning.

Here's a quick example similar to the picture up above:

```html
    <img 
    alt="104,{Start B}" title="104,{Start B}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/AC3gAT0BDuLeG4IAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="30" height="30"><img
    alt=" 17,A:{1},B:{1}" title=" 17,A:{1},B:{1}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/AGMgAOkAhBjTObMAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="30" height="30"><img
    alt=" 18,A:{2},B:{2}" title=" 18,A:{2},B:{2}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/ADGgAQUA0nI/mr0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="30" height="30"><img
    alt=" 19,A:{3},B:{3}" title=" 19,A:{3},B:{3}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/ADRgAMsAlQDS68kAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="30" height="30"><img
    alt=" 08,A:{(},B:{(}" title=" 08,A:{(},B:{(}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/AHNgAUkA1ElZCJAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="30" height="30"><img
    alt="106,{Stop}"title="106,{Stop}"src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAA0AAAABAQMAAAA/57ZEAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/ADigARMA2dpJzT8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="30" height="30">
    <p/>
    123
    <br>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <img 
    alt="104,{Start B}" title="104,{Start B}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/AC3gAT0BDuLeG4IAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="9" height="30"><img
    alt=" 17,A:{1},B:{1}" title=" 17,A:{1},B:{1}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/AGMgAOkAhBjTObMAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="9" height="30"><img
    alt=" 18,A:{2},B:{2}" title=" 18,A:{2},B:{2}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/ADGgAQUA0nI/mr0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="9" height="30"><img
    alt=" 19,A:{3},B:{3}" title=" 19,A:{3},B:{3}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/ADRgAMsAlQDS68kAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="9" height="30"><img
    alt=" 20,A:{4},B:{4}" title=" 20,A:{4},B:{4}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/ADYgAI8AVxcQlAsAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="9" height="30"><img
    alt=" 21,A:{5},B:{5}" title=" 21,A:{5},B:{5}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/ACNgAKkAhD/i5lYAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="9" height="30"><img
    alt=" 22,A:{6},B:{6}" title=" 22,A:{6},B:{6}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/ADFgAMUAksTlwtMAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="9" height="30"><img
    alt=" 23,A:{7},B:{7}" title=" 23,A:{7},B:{7}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/ABIgAEcAM15OsZIAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="9" height="30"><img
    alt=" 24,A:{8},B:{8}" title=" 24,A:{8},B:{8}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/ABZgAI8Ad3Mh6bwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="9" height="30"><img
    alt=" 25,A:{9},B:{9}" title=" 25,A:{9},B:{9}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/ABpgAJcAex9glyQAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="9" height="30"><img
    alt=" 16,A:{0},B:{0}" title=" 16,A:{0},B:{0}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/AGJgAScAw0BJukMAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="9" height="30"><img
    alt=" 17,A:{1},B:{1}" title=" 17,A:{1},B:{1}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/AGMgAOkAhBjTObMAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="9" height="30"><img
    alt=" 18,A:{2},B:{2}" title=" 18,A:{2},B:{2}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/ADGgAQUA0nI/mr0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="9" height="30"><img
    alt=" 19,A:{3},B:{3}" title=" 19,A:{3},B:{3}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/ADRgAMsAlQDS68kAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="9" height="30"><img
    alt=" 20,A:{4},B:{4}" title=" 20,A:{4},B:{4}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/ADYgAI8AVxcQlAsAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="9" height="30"><img
    alt=" 21,A:{5},B:{5}" title=" 21,A:{5},B:{5}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/ACNgAKkAhD/i5lYAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="9" height="30"><img
    alt=" 22,A:{6},B:{6}" title=" 22,A:{6},B:{6}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/ADFgAMUAksTlwtMAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="9" height="30"><img
    alt=" 23,A:{7},B:{7}" title=" 23,A:{7},B:{7}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/ABIgAEcAM15OsZIAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="9" height="30"><img
    alt=" 64,A:{NUL},B:{`}" title=" 64,A:{NUL},B:{`}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/AF5gAR8Av0A69KoAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="9" height="30"><img
    alt="106,{Stop}"title="106,{Stop}"src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAA0AAAABAQMAAAA/57ZEAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/ADigARMA2dpJzT8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="9" height="30">
    <p/>
    12345678901234567
```

Note that the dimensions are specified for each character and the barcodes will generally scan at a width of 8 or higher (depending on print quality). All characters within a barcode need identical widths. Remember that your horizontal quiet zone is a function of bar width, so try to keep at least two character widths to each side on the label.

Comment: Very interesting! I'll take a look at this; thanks a lot for your answer. My scanner seems to have a problem to read the one with more data on less space, though. (From my screen, I'll try it on paper tomorrow when I get access to a printer)

Comment: Yes, the browser does not necessarily produce scanable barcodes due to the anti-aliasing filter applied to the display. When the page is printed, however, the barcode scans quite well on paper. You can access the complete font at http://notionovus.com/blog/code-128-barcode/

Comment: I tried it out, and it worked great on paper! On some angles, the more "comprimated" code was somewhat harder to read. Many, many thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 4):

I think the best thing to do is pad your data, i.e.

```
123
```

Becomes

```
00000000000000123
```

Just from thinking about how other places do it, I've definitely seen zero padded barcodes in my day-to-day life before. I think the best thing to do is just pick a number of digits that you think will be sufficient for years and code your application to that number. If you end up having to go beyond it, well, that's a good problem to have, isn't it?

Comment: The code is a mix of numbers and characters, although mostly numbers. This complicates things a bit?

Comment: In order for me (or anyone) to help you with that, we'd need to know more about how these barcodes are generated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is also a good solution to my problem, however Brian's answer were more suitable for long-term. I'll keep your answer in mind, though, thanks again!