# How to generate fix size of barcode whether it's 3 char or 8 char?

Tags: php, codeigniter, barcode

I am using one of third party class file to generate barcode with php dynamically as per user inputs. I have problem with it's variable size of width.

When user enters 3 char then it creates small width of barcode and when user enters 10-14 chars, then it generates big barcode in width. I want barcode with same height - width in all cases.

See my app details:

- PHP 5.6
- CI3 framework
- barcode type : code128

Please see my code below:

```
public function barcode( $filepath="", $text="USPC", $size="43", $orientation="horizontal", $code_type="code128", $print=false, $SizeFactor=1 ) {
    $code_string = "";

$chksum = 104;
        // Must not change order of array elements as the checksum depends on the array's key to validate final code
        $code_array = array(" "=>"212222","!"=>"222122","\""=>"222221","#"=>"121223","$"=>"121322","%"=>"131222","&"=>"122213","'"=>"122312","("=>"132212",")"=>"221213","*"=>"221312","+"=>"231212",","=>"112232","-"=>"122132","."=>"122231","/"=>"113222","0"=>"123122","1"=>"123221","2"=>"223211","3"=>"221132","4"=>"221231","5"=>"213212","6"=>"223112","7"=>"312131","8"=>"311222","9"=>"321122",":"=>"321221",";"=>"312212","<"=>"322112","="=>"322211",">"=>"212123","?"=>"212321","@"=>"232121","A"=>"111323","B"=>"131123","C"=>"131321","D"=>"112313","E"=>"132113","F"=>"132311","G"=>"211313","H"=>"231113","I"=>"231311","J"=>"112133","K"=>"112331","L"=>"132131","M"=>"113123","N"=>"113321","O"=>"133121","P"=>"313121","Q"=>"211331","R"=>"231131","S"=>"213113","T"=>"213311","U"=>"213131","V"=>"311123","W"=>"311321","X"=>"331121","Y"=>"312113","Z"=>"312311","["=>"332111","\\"=>"314111","]"=>"221411","^"=>"431111","_"=>"111224","\`"=>"111422","a"=>"121124","b"=>"121421","c"=>"141122","d"=>"141221","e"=>"112214","f"=>"112412","g"=>"122114","h"=>"122411","i"=>"142112","j"=>"142211","k"=>"241211","l"=>"221114","m"=>"413111","n"=>"241112","o"=>"134111","p"=>"111242","q"=>"121142","r"=>"121241","s"=>"114212","t"=>"124112","u"=>"124211","v"=>"411212","w"=>"421112","x"=>"421211","y"=>"212141","z"=>"214121","{"=>"412121","|"=>"111143","}"=>"111341","~"=>"131141","DEL"=>"114113","FNC 3"=>"114311","FNC 2"=>"411113","SHIFT"=>"411311","CODE C"=>"113141","FNC 4"=>"114131","CODE A"=>"311141","FNC 1"=>"411131","Start A"=>"211412","Start B"=>"211214","Start C"=>"211232","Stop"=>"2331112");
        $code_keys = array_keys($code_array);
        $code_values = array_flip($code_keys);
        for ( $X = 1; $X <= strlen($text); $X++ ) {
            $activeKey = substr( $text, ($X-1), 1);
            $code_string .= $code_array[$activeKey];
            $chksum=($chksum + ($code_values[$activeKey] * $X));
        }
        $code_string .= $code_array[$code_keys[($chksum - (intval($chksum / 103) * 103))]];
        $code_string = "211214" . $code_string . "2331112";
    $code_length = 20;
    if ($print) {
        $text_height = 30;
    } else {
        $text_height = 0;
    }

    for ( $i=1; $i <= strlen($code_string); $i++ ){
        $code_length = $code_length + (integer)(substr($code_string,($i-1),1));
        }

    if ( strtolower($orientation) == "horizontal" ) {
        $img_width = $code_length*$SizeFactor;
        $img_height = 192;
        $img_width=384;// set hardcoded height -width as client suggested
    } else {
        $img_width = 384;
        $img_height = $code_length*$SizeFactor;
    }

    $image = imagecreate($img_width, $img_height + $text_height);
    $black = imagecolorallocate ($image, 0, 0, 0);
    $white = imagecolorallocate ($image, 255, 255, 255);

    imagefill( $image, 0, 0, $white );
    if ( $print ) {
        imagestring($image, 5, 31, $img_height, $text, $black );
    }

    $location = 10;
    for ( $position = 1 ; $position <= strlen($code_string); $position++ ) {
        $cur_size = $location + ( substr($code_string, ($position-1), 1) );
        if ( strtolower($orientation) == "horizontal" )
            imagefilledrectangle( $image, $location*$SizeFactor, 0, $cur_size*$SizeFactor, $img_height, ($position % 2 == 0 ? $white : $black) );
        else
            imagefilledrectangle( $image, 0, $location*$SizeFactor, $img_width, $cur_size*$SizeFactor, ($position % 2 == 0 ? $white : $black) );
        $location = $cur_size;
    }
// Draw barcode to the screen or save in a file
    if ( $filepath=="" ) {
        header ('Content-type: image/png');
        imagepng($image);
        imagedestroy($image);
    } else {
        imagepng($image,$filepath);
        imagedestroy($image);       
    }
}
```

Can this be achieved?

Comment: Would something like my answer to this question help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13768651/how-to-achieve-constant-width-for-barcodes-regardless-of-barcode-data/13773171#13773171

Answer (score 1):

If Someone is still looking for this answer, this is how it can be done.

I am using the CodeItNow barcode generator available at Github. Details https://github.com/codeitnowin/barcode-generator here.

After Setup, use this code.

```
<?php
use CodeItNow\BarcodeBundle\Utils\QrCode;
use CodeItNow\BarcodeBundle\Utils\BarcodeGenerator;
$barcode = new BarcodeGenerator();
$barcode->setText("Any Data You Need To Be Here");
$barcode->setType(BarcodeGenerator::Code128);
$barcode->setScale(2);
$barcode->setThickness(25);
$barcode->setFontSize(10);
$barcode->setlabel("Any Label for Barcode");
$code = $barcode->generate();

echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.$code.'" width="400" height="60"/>';
?>
```

The width and height of the barcode can be defined in the image tag.

Comment: The library CodeItNow is infringing Barcode Bakery copyright. If you need to generate barcodes, you can use our library https://www.barcodebakery.com/ ; I work for Barcode Bakery.